# Javascript array reduce convert array to object with integer keys

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert an array of objects to objects with reduce method. The problem is I want to have object keys in numeric.

```js
let crops = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "wheat"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "rice"
}];

let cropsObj = crops.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator[currentValue.id] = currentValue.name
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(cropsObj);
```

This works fine except the keys I am getting are strings. For example:

```
{"1":"wheat","2":"rice"}
```

What I want is  `{1:"wheat",2:"rice"}`. How can I convert the keys to integers?

Comment: Keys can only be strings (or Symbols) in javascript objects. If you need some other key an es6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) might be an option.

Comment: An array has integer "keys", but there are performance implications to sparse arrays. You might want to look into `Map`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey If neglecting performance for a moment, How will I have integer keys ?

Comment: `{"1":"wheat","2":"rice"}` and `{1:"wheat",2:"rice"}` are same thing, JS internally converts them to string

Comment: The problem here is I have to pass this object to a third party library which requires Object. https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable the last example has the `lookup` key

Comment: @RaheelKhan that is still the same thing

Comment: @Rik Yeah It works this way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes (using material-table), your current objects will work fine. `{1:"wheat"}` is effectively the same as `{"1":"wheat"}`.

[Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties) gives a very detailed explanation of why. In short, numeric property names can be used, but they will be coerced into strings.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate @MarkMeyer's comment:

> Keys can only be strings (or Symbols) in javascript objects.

```js
console.log({3: 4, '3': 5});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
  key: 4,
  123: 'one two three',
  1: 'one'
};

console.log(obj.key);
//console.log(obj.1); error
console.log(obj["1"]);
console.log(obj["123"]);

console.log(obj[1]);
console.log(obj[123]);
```

It is not possible because key in any JavaScript object is a JavaScript `identifier` or a `string`.